# How can I check existing patches into a Mercurial queue repository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have an existing queue directory with a number patches already in it.  I am about to fold them into a single commit but I would like to preserve the original patches before I do that.  How can I do that?

This is what I tried so far:

```
$ hg ci --mq
abort: no queue repository
```

Then, since I have enough knowledge to be dangerous, I tried to create the patch repository manually:

```
$ cd .hg/patches/
/Users/me/Code/my-project/.hg/patches
$ hg init
$ cd -
/Users/me/Code/my-project
```

But when I try to commit, it won't let me:

```
$ hg ci --mq
nothing changed
```

The patch repository can be deleted if the solution requires it.  It's empty so that's safe to do.